# Adjusting Index for Better Performance

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index

I've just started my journey as a dba and I figured out using a script that my database indexes are a mess. Here they are: [image: Indexes in table Dados]

And here is what the script tells me about them:
[image: Script optimization suggestions]

Can you give me insights about how to fix them and what I should consider (logically speaking) when doing it? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data. Please paste them in as text.

Comment: Without knowing your read and write queries we can't really help. As a reductio ad absurdum, if you are not querying the table then you don't need any indexes and should drop them all.

Comment: What specific thing do you want to improve the performance of? (Hint: what are users saying is slow). Start analyzing that problem so you can solve it. Going through these results is just going to give you extra work and probably not help anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed with everyone's comments so far, most importantly with index tuning is understanding your queries use cases so you know what indexes are being used, what indexes are missing and could be helpful, and what indexes are wasteful.

It looks like you're using scripts from the [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/), such as `sp_BlitzIndex` which is really helpful for identifying the aforementioned types of index tuning. For example, it should give you metrics on how many `Reads` vs `Writes` each index incurs. Indexes with 0 reads are generally useless. This means no query is actually using that index. Indexes with a very small amount of reads with a high number of writes *might* not be worth keeping (but should be tested first before removing in Production). In some cases, that index might still be very important for a query that isn't ran frequently.

It should be noted that these metrics should be analyzed keeping the uptime of your server in mind. If your server was just restarted yesterday, then the metrics are only going to be based off data that's been collected since yesterday (for the most part). Servers with at least 6 months or more uptime should have enough data to safely analyze.

Finally, I do see some freebies in the little information we do have from the screenshots you've provided - redundant indexes. It's a waste to have multiple indexes that cover the same fields from a table. One example of this that I see in your results is `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao` and `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao_Includes`. `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao_Includes` already covers all the same fields as `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao` plus some additional use cases with the included columns. That means `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao` is a redundant and unnecessary index that almost certainly can be dropped. And any other indexes that are defined on any sequential subset of the same fields in `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao_Includes` or any other index are also redundant and already covered, so they too very likely can be removed. For example an index on the fields `(D, C, B, A)` will cover all the same use cases as an index just on `(D)`, or an index on `(D, C)`, or an index on `(D, C, B)`. So the only index needed in that case is `(D, C, B, A)`.

My final advice, even on the recommended certainties above, is to ensure you test the changes thoroughly in a non-Production environment before deploying the changes to a Production environment.

Comment: I'm following your advice and testing all the changes in a development enviroment. I have some doubts about those Borderline duplicate keys and about what you pointed out here "cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao_Includes already covers all the same fields as cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao". 


First doubt -> Suppose I have this index: 
cod_ponto {real 4}, hora_leit {datetime 8}, delay {int 4}, nivel_agua {float 8}


Do I have to follow all this column definitions and this order in a query? For ex: Imagine I don't pass a delay, is the index still usefull?

Comment: Second doubt -> my cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao had those statistics before I stopped it: reads: 30k writes: 25k and my cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao_Includes reads: 9k writes: writes: 25k... does it mean that the first index was helping/performing better?

Comment: @BookWritter To your first question: `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao_Includes` covers all the same fields as `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao` and has additional columns in the includes part of it. This means it can be used for all of the same predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` clauses) as the index `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao` can be used for. E.g. if your query said `WHERE cod_ponto = 7` or if it said `WHERE cod_ponto = 4 AND hora_leit = '2022-09-09'` both indexes can cover both of these examples just the same, so `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao` is redundant.

Comment: To your second question: It means both indexes were being used, and it was probably partly random when one got chosen over the other for a certain scenario. But they are still redundant and if you drop the index `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao`, then the other index `cod_ponto_hora_leit_vazao_Includes` will likely get used in its place for those other queries / cases.